# Pros and cons of using modem as a router?

Tags: networking, router, modem

Recently changed internet service package and received a brand new ISP modem that can also act as a router.
Before, had a dedicated modem that had a Linksys router connected to it.
Was pondering if I should make things simple for myself and retire my Linksys router in favor of this new modem-router.
What are some pros and cons of doing that?
I gain by having mode space freed up and less cabling.
But will I sacrifice something? ISP being able to sniff my packets more easily?

Comment: Since you were not using the linksys to encrypt your data removing the LInksys has 0 impact on your ISP sniffing your traffic.  If it is not encrypted,if your ISP wants your data they got it.

Comment: @cybernard How do I know if I encrypt my traffic on Linksys? I have all security settings turned on to the max.

Comment: besides https website your system does not normally encrypt anything.  I don't think any linksys devices have built-in support for Tor or similiar networking so nothing is encrypted by your linksys.  Firefox,Chrome,IE,or etc will encrypt https traffic but that is it.

Comment: Any ISP is technically able to see any unencrypted Internet traffic, no matter the modem/router used on the subscriber's end. As for non Internet (i.e. LAN) traffic, I have never heard of any ISP ever trying to sniff it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISP-provided gear is almost always cheap crap. Unless your Linksys box is really old or was a low-end cheap crap box to begin with, it's probably higher quality than what your ISP gave you.

On the other hand, check the wireless technology on the new box and compare to your existing router. Maybe the ISP box is simultaneous dual-band but your old Linksys was 2.4GHz only. Or maybe your new box is 802.11ac and your old box was 802.11n. Maybe a cheap crap version of a newer faster technology is better than a solid implementation of an obsolete technology.

Comment: This answer covers it well. Privacy wise though, using your own router behind their CPE does reduce their view of your LAN. They can still see every frame you send to WAN, but cant access your ARP tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends wether you are talking about a Wifi router or a regular Ethernet router.

- If your routers are Wifi routers, then experiment and stick to the one that has the best signal quality.
- If you only use the router with Ethernet, don't bother with an extra equipment (unless you find the ISP provided router is missing admin features). You won't notice any difference in performance.